# Wamp won't uinstall vunistall.dat is missing

Tags: wamp, uninstallation

Please, I need assistance. I would like to uninstall my wamp server from my windows 10 computer.
When ever I try use control panel it keeps saying "vunins000.dat" is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have delete the "vunins000.dat" file.
If you want to uninstall wamp server delete the folder C:\wamp 

**Warning:** Make sure you have backup your databases and sites first.